# Spring Data save doesn't DELETE

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

`removeRecipe` in Cookbook removes a `Recipe` from a `Cookbook`. After setting the references to null and removing the entity from the collections the entity is not deleted.

```
@Entity
public class Cookbook implements Identifiable<Cookbook> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Cookbook.class);
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private List<CookbookRecipe> cookbookRecipes = new ArrayList<>();

    public Cookbook() {}

    public Cookbook(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "cookbook", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<CookbookRecipe> getCookbookRecipes() {
        return cookbookRecipes;
    }

    /**
     * The setter is called by hibernate.
     * @param cookbookRecipes maybe null, maybe the collection is not even ready for read access.
     *                    Don't do anything with the collection here!
     */
    public void setCookbookRecipes(List<CookbookRecipe> cookbookRecipes) {
        this.cookbookRecipes = cookbookRecipes;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a List that must remain unchanged.
     */
    @Transient
    public List<Recipe> getRecipes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(getCookbookRecipes().stream().map(CookbookRecipe::getRecipe).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe, String createdBy, Date createdDate) {
        final CookbookRecipe cookbookRecipe = new CookbookRecipe(this, recipe);
        cookbookRecipe.setCreatedBy(createdBy);
        cookbookRecipe.setCreatedDate(createdDate);
        if( !cookbookRecipes.contains(cookbookRecipe) && !recipe.getCookbookRecipes().contains(cookbookRecipe)) {
            if( !cookbookRecipes.add(cookbookRecipe) ) {
                LOG.error("Failed to add cookbookRecipe " + cookbookRecipe + " to collection cookbookRecipes " + cookbookRecipes);
            }
            if( !recipe.getCookbookRecipes().add( cookbookRecipe ) ) {
                LOG.error("Failed to add cookbookRecipe " + cookbookRecipe + " to collection recipe.getCookbookRecipes " + recipe.getCookbookRecipes());
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeRecipe(Recipe recipe) {

        for (Iterator<CookbookRecipe> iterator = cookbookRecipes.iterator();
             iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            CookbookRecipe cookbookRecipe = iterator.next();

            if (cookbookRecipe.getCookbook().equals(this) &&
                    cookbookRecipe.getRecipe().equals(recipe)) {
                iterator.remove();
                recipe.getCookbookRecipes().remove(cookbookRecipe);
                cookbookRecipe.setCookbook(null);
                cookbookRecipe.setRecipe(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Cookbook that = (Cookbook) o;
        return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equalsByBusinessKey(Cookbook other) {
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (other == null || getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;
        return Objects.equals(getTitle(), other.getTitle());
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cookbook_recipe")
public class CookbookRecipe implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CookbookRecipePk pk;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @MapsId("cookbookId")
    private Cookbook cookbook;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @MapsId("recipeId")
    private Recipe recipe;

    private Date createdDate;
    private String createdBy;

    public CookbookRecipe() {
    }

    public CookbookRecipe(Cookbook cookbook, Recipe recipe) {
        this.cookbook = cookbook;
        this.recipe = recipe;
        this.pk = new CookbookRecipePk(cookbook.getId(), recipe.getId());
    }

    public CookbookRecipePk getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(CookbookRecipePk pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Cookbook getCookbook() {
        return cookbook;
    }

    public void setCookbook(Cookbook cookbook) {
        this.cookbook = cookbook;
    }

    @Transient
    public Recipe getRecipe() {
        return recipe;
    }

    public void setRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        this.recipe = recipe;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        CookbookRecipe that = (CookbookRecipe) o;

        return Objects.equals(getPk(), that.getPk());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("CookbookRecipe{");
        sb.append("pk=")
          .append(pk);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class CookbookRecipePk implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Column(name = "cookbook_id")
    private Long cookbookId;

    @Column(name = "recipe_id")
    private Long recipeId;

    public CookbookRecipePk() {}

    public CookbookRecipePk(Long cookbookId, Long recipeId) {
        this.cookbookId = cookbookId;
        this.recipeId = recipeId;
    }

    public Long getCookbookId() {
        return cookbookId;
    }

    public void setCookbookId(Long cookbookId) {
        this.cookbookId = cookbookId;
    }

    public Long getRecipeId() {
        return recipeId;
    }

    public void setRecipeId(Long recipeId) {
        this.recipeId = recipeId;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        CookbookRecipePk that = (CookbookRecipePk) o;

        return null != cookbookId && null != recipeId &&
                Objects.equals(cookbookId, that.cookbookId) &&
                Objects.equals(recipeId, that.recipeId);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("CookbookRecipePk{");
        sb.append("cookbookId=")
          .append(cookbookId);
        sb.append(", recipeId=")
          .append(recipeId);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

@Entity
public class Recipe implements Serializable, Identifiable<Recipe> {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Category category;
    private List<CookbookRecipe> cookbookRecipes = new ArrayList<>();

    public Recipe(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Recipe() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<CookbookRecipe> getCookbookRecipes() {
        return cookbookRecipes;
    }

    public void setCookbookRecipes(List<CookbookRecipe> cookbookRecipes) {
        this.cookbookRecipes = cookbookRecipes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Recipe that = (Recipe) o;
        return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Recipe{");
        sb.append("id=")
          .append(id);
        sb.append(", title='")
          .append(title)
          .append('\'');
        sb.append(", cookbookRecipes=")
          .append(cookbookRecipes);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equalsByBusinessKey(Recipe other) {
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (other == null || getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;
        return Objects.equals(getTitle(), other.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class CookbookRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    RecipeRepository recipeRepository;
    @Autowired
    CookbookRepository cookbookRepository;
    @Autowired
    CookbookRecipeRepository cookbookRecipeRepository;

    @Test
    public void WhenAddingSameAssociationAgain_ThenNoException() {
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        recipe.setTitle("A Recipe");
        recipe = recipeRepository.save(recipe);

        Cookbook cookbook = new Cookbook();
        cookbook.setTitle("A Cookbook");
        cookbook = cookbookRepository.save(cookbook);

        cookbook.addRecipe(recipe, "integrationtest", new Date());
        cookbook = cookbookRepository.save(cookbook);

        cookbook.removeRecipe(recipe);
        cookbook = cookbookRepository.save(cookbook);
        assertThat(cookbookRecipeRepository.findAll().size(), is(0));
    }

}
```

The assertion fails. I don't understand why.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <0>
     but: was <1>
```

I expect JPA to generate a DELETE statement, because orphanRemoval is set to true. Instead the CookbookRecipe.recipeId and CookbookRecipe.cookbookId are set to null in the database but they are not removed.

Comment: You're supposed to call something like `RecipeRepository.delete(Recipe)` to delete a `Recipe` entity. Setting references to `null` is not enough.

Comment: I don't want to delete a recipe. I want to remove a recipe from a cookbook. Thereby the association has to be removed. But JPA doesn't create the necessary DELETE statement even when orphanRemoval is true. Instead the values are set to null, which is fine but not enough.

Comment: I dont know the answer but curious to know what is overridden equalsByBusinessKey(...) where does this come from?

Comment: @FakirTrappedInCode please read http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html and then decide not to introduce a uuid. Imagine a Cookbook(id: 1, title: "H") and Cookbook(id: null, title: "H"). There shall be one cookbook with the same title. Before adding both to a collection you commonly have to check if they "mean the same thing" in respect to your business rules. This is comes in handy if you have mixed collections with unpers. and persisted objects in a gui app. You can't use equals because it would return false.

Answer (score 0):

i think the Entity its not removed because the 'CookbookRecipe' entity its mapped @oneToMany in 2 ways  , from 'cookbook' and from 'recipe' in this way you cant delete recipe from cookbook because Spring data accepts commands from 2 entities , u must cancel the second conf oneTOMany from recipe and will working as well , Also u can use the @query in repository (Writing a custom query delete and will work as Well ) , i faced this problem one year ago , hope is useful ,